# java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: 'void Student.<init>(int, java.lang.String)' at oops5.main(oops5.java:18)

Tags: java, loops

Constructor

[image]

I am trying to use the constructor in this program but it show this error.

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: 'void Student.<init>(int, java.lang.String)'
        at oops5.main(oops5.java:18)
```

Comment: Do a class `Student` exist in any of the other `oops` files? I bet they do. You can't do that: They're overwriting each other. Either turn them into inner classes, or, give them all a unique name, or, put all `oops` files into their own package.

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors.](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/85421) <- and read that link to understand why

Comment: please delete all .class files and then compile and run. code looks fine..

Answer (score 0):

This is a simple Java program.
I will recommend to use Notepad and Command Prompt for same. To do so, you are required to configure Java Bin Path of System variables (for Windows, Environment Variables of Advanced system settings). Then open command prompt and enter below commands:

1. `cd FileFolderPath`
2. `javac oops5.java`
3. `java oops5`